# FB.Canvas.setSize() -- no parameter / auto-resize not working

Tags: facebook, debugging

We called the setSize with no parameter and it is not working.

```
FB.Canvas.setSize();
```

at Jul 18, don't work
at Jul 17, work

I have searched on the internet that many people have this problem.
But most fixes are related to the call with parameters, i.e. FB.Canvas.setSize({width height});

Answer (score 0):

If `setSize` only works with parameters for you, you can use jQuery to determine the current size of your body (the html body, you know what I mean...):

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ $(document.body).width(), $(document.body).height() });
```

Comment: Another guess: Have you initialized Facebook with `FB.init`? Please update your question with a detailed code snippet. Otherwise you will get only more guesses from the community.